# Can I use the voice to open flutter application?

Tags: flutter, background-process, voice-detection

I am working on developing an application to help the blind to find things, and I want to add to the application the feature of operating by voice, for example, when the user says “Open” the application will lunch

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that is possible to use a custom text, but you can open the app using the "Ok Google" like:

- "Ok Google, open `yourAppName`"

or

- "Ok Google, open `yourAppName` application"

Comment: And the same should also work for Siri. "Hey Siri, open <app>"